# Column width for <th> not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my html:

```
     <html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">    

<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body style="padding-top: 47px;">

<table class="table table-hover table-striped-custom">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 5px;"></th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>column2</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: #FF5F5F;width: 5px;"></td>
                <td>blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
                <td>bla</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: deepskyblue"></td>
                <td>bla</td>
                <td>bla</td>
            </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Problem is when setting width for first column: it won't go under 16px. If I put bigger width(20,50), colored column become larger, but when I try to set them  thinner (for example 7px), It doesn't take any effect.
How can I do it, without removing any css class from existing template. Colored column have to be first, it's height must be as row's height and I have to be able to set it's width to any value I want.

Comment: Seems to work here http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/qq3L0o77/. Oops nevermind, it breaks after you add bootstrap http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/qq3L0o77/1/

Comment: something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3a5vgm2c/)?

Comment: @Litestone Read my comment, the problem happens when you add bootstrap

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because your bootstrap css is adding 8px padding to the table cells (which is why your min width is 16px: 8px left plus 8px right) - try adding `padding:0;` for those cells and it should work

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gux44wmx/3/)

Comment: Note that to add it in a CSS section will require a lot of specificity since bootstrap uses `.table>thead>tr>td`

Comment: @JuanMendes As OP is using inline styles, they should override the stylesheet styles, otherwise yes they will need to be more specific than the css in the bootstrap

Comment: That's what I said, if the OP is going to move to using best practices, they'll need to use high specificity. I never said what you have doesn't work, but I'm sure we agree it's not the best way to do things.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that bootstrap has set `min-width` on `th` or `td`. If so, I'd add an additional style block (in the HTML, if you can't add/edit external CSS), to allow the first column to be as small as you like:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .table td:first-child, .table th:first-child {
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
```